# Add single row to bottom of nested element in XML using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to include a single line for 'Frequency' at the bottom of a nested XML element. At the moment, my code is putting the frequency line outside of the returns section. I would like this to appear within it, as a single line at the bottom. I have the below code which is almost there. Current output and desired output are also shown:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT  
    'USD' AS 'Currency',   
    'TestDatabase' AS 'Datasource',
    'Test Name' AS 'Name',
            (SELECT
            ValueDate AS 'Date',
            ReturnValue AS 'ROR'
            FROM FactReturn [Value]
            WHERE [Value].AssetId = asset.AssetId
            FOR XML AUTO,TYPE, ROOT('Returns')),
     'Daily' AS 'Frequency'
     FROM DimAsset Asset
     FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('Assets'))
FOR  XML PATH('Body'),ROOT('ASPackage')
```

Result:

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsY4u.png)

Desired Result:

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdmSF.png)

Comment: The posted query is not valid... Please edit this, try to add some indents, to group your sub-selects visually. Try to create a full *stand-alone* example with minimized table(s) and appropriate sample data.

Comment: And please tag with the actual database product you are using (I assume it's `[sql-server]`).

Comment: Hi Shnugo, thanks for the help - Query updated

Answer (score 0):

I asked you to provide some minimized tables with appropriate sample data. What I've done to set up a test scenario with mockup objects should be your job the next time...

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @DimAssetMockup TABLE(AssetID INT,AssesName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @DimAssetMockup VALUES(1,'Asset 1'),(2,'Asset 2');

DECLARE @FactReturnMockup TABLE(AssetID INT,ValueDate DATETIME, ReturnValue DECIMAL(12,10))
INSERT INTO @FactReturnMockup VALUES(1,{d'2017-01-01'},0.11)
                                   ,(1,{d'2017-01-02'},0.12)
                                   ,(2,{d'2017-02-01'},0.21)
                                   ,(2,{d'2017-02-02'},0.22);

SELECT
(
    SELECT 'USD' AS 'Currency'
          ,'TestDatabase' AS 'Datasource'
          ,AssesName AS [Name]
          ,(
            SELECT [Value].ValueDate AS [@Date]
                  ,[Value].ReturnValue as [@ROR]
            FROM @FactReturnMockup AS [Value]
            WHERE [Value].AssetID=Asset.AssetID
            FOR XML PATH('Value'),TYPE
           ) AS [Returns]
          ,'Daily' AS [Returns/Frequency]
    FROM @DimAssetMockup Asset
    FOR XML PATH('Asset'),ROOT('Assets'),TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH('Body'),ROOT('ASPackage');
```

The result

```
<ASPackage>
  <Body>
    <Assets>
      <Asset>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <Datasource>TestDatabase</Datasource>
        <Name>Asset 1</Name>
        <Returns>
          <Value Date="2017-01-01T00:00:00" ROR="0.1100000000" />
          <Value Date="2017-01-02T00:00:00" ROR="0.1200000000" />
          <Frequency>Daily</Frequency>
        </Returns>
      </Asset>
      <Asset>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
        <Datasource>TestDatabase</Datasource>
        <Name>Asset 2</Name>
        <Returns>
          <Value Date="2017-02-01T00:00:00" ROR="0.2100000000" />
          <Value Date="2017-02-02T00:00:00" ROR="0.2200000000" />
          <Frequency>Daily</Frequency>
        </Returns>
      </Asset>
    </Assets>
  </Body>
</ASPackage>
```